# How do I make my script ask for a password, like sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, passwords, password-protection

I am writing a script which would be potentially dangerous if run in the wrong way. As a safety feature, I want the script to require the user to re-enter their password first, much as `sudo` does.

So how do I do this? In other words how do I

a) input the password without echoing it,

b) verify the password, and

c) (for bonus points) do this without leaving the plaintext password lying around in memory for some clever chap to scrape out of /proc or something like that?

This is in `bash` but any other standard Linux shell variant would be ok if that's easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
su $USER -c true
```

And then test the return value in $?. For example:

```
echo "Really delete everything? Enter your password to confirm:"
su $USER -c true && rm -rf $HOME
```

The `true` is there solely as a no-op.

To suppress the output from su you can redirect stderr:

```
echo -n "Enter password for $USER:"
su $USER -c true 2>/dev/null  && echo -e "\nsuccess" || echo -e "\nfailure"
```

You cannot omit the -c [command] parameter as this will create a new interactive instance of bash (whether you group it in subshells or not):

```
$ ((su $USER ) && echo ok) ; echo "exit status:$?"
Password: 
$ echo $SHLVL 
2
$ exit
ok
exit status:0
$ echo $SHLVL 
1
```

So the example in the comments below:

```
((su $USER >/dev/null 2>&1) && echo ok) || echo no
```

did not display anything (unless su authentication failed) because with a correct password you are now working in a nested shell (with all screen output redirected). Press CTRL-D (to exit the shell) and you will see "ok" echoed.

Comment: Great solution! You may want to redirect the output of su to `/dev/null` to prevent "su: Authentication failure" output in case of a wrong password.

Comment: @Tim Like so: `su $USER -c "echo -n" >/dev/null 2>&1` (`&>/dev/null` will do both redirections in at least `bash` and `zsh`, but it's not standard)

Comment: Testing it now, seems like `-c "echo -n"` is redundant. Is my ubuntu abnormal in that regard?

Comment: @spraff The `-c` flag to `su` tells it to execute a single command. Otherwise, it would log the user in again, which is redundant.

Comment: Thanks. Quick follow-up: my test is `((su $USER >/dev/null 2>&1) && echo ok) || echo no` which prints "no" when the password is wrong and prints NOTHING when the password is right. Why is this, do you know?

Comment: @BlacklightShining Just tested it again. Since both the password prompt and the error message are on channel 2, suppression of the message does not seem to be possible (at least not without a lot of additional `echo`s). Just forget my comment...

Comment: @Tim Oh, darn. Well…we want a custom prompt anyway, right?

Comment: @spraff you removed the `-c "echo -n"`. Now you are actually opening a subshell. The "ok" is printed when you logout (CTRL+D or exit). Also the redirection does make your in- and output invisible as long as you are in the subshell.

Comment: @spraff [It's because `su` is starting another session; the `echo` is never executed.](http://superuser.com/a/191147/144700) That's why you use `-c "echo -n"`.

Comment: …that post has the _opposite_ problem as yours. XD

Comment: Tim and spraff, you may want to keep an eye on [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49931/how-to-suppress-su-authentication-failure-warning). :)

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best practice here is to require admin privileges to run the script by changing the file permissions / ownership. That way you use the default implementation instead of having to re-invent the wheel by building a custom password checking feature (in other words, you require the user to either be logged in as root, be in the sudoers list and use `sudo` or use `su` to become root).

Right click on the script, click on Properties and then on the Permissions tab to change permissions / ownership. Or use `chmod` / `chown` to do so (see the man pages for more info). Do all this as root.

Comment: If someone is already tunning a root shell that won't work. I don't want admin privileges, I want to reverify the password. Overlapping but not equivalent problems.

Comment: -1: doesn't answer the question, mostly irrelevant (see @spraff's comment)